# Core Data Null Relationship

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a to-one relationship in my data model with Core Data. I'm trying to set the value of the relationship but Core Data keeps thinking that it's nil. The "creatorUser" relationship is **not optional**, so when I go to save my managed object context, Core Data gives errors because it thinks the "creatorUser" is nil.

Any help would be greatly advised.

```
NSManagedObject *teamManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DCTeam" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
// Creator Properties
NSManagedObject *creator = [self userForID:[ticketInfo objectForKey:@"userid"]];
if (!creator) {
    creator = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DCUser" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

    [creator setValue:[personInfo objectForKey:@"userid"] forKey:@"userid"];
    [creator setValue:[personInfo objectForKey:@"creatorName"] forKey:@"name"];
}

[teamManagedObject setValue:creator forKey:@"creatorUser"];
```

Comment: You'll probably need to post a picture of the object graph so we can see your relationships. You can also post it textually like: teamManagedObject.creatorUser--(optionalFlag,deleterule)->creator. Use one '-->' of to one and '-->>' for to many.

Comment: Dylan Copeland: Please edit your question to include whatever exception message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was getting was '1570'. That's the one that says that a non-optional relationship is nil. nall is correct, the relationship was supposed to be a to-many. This was an oversight by myself which is why Core Data didn't like pairing up the relationship.

Thanks to all that replied!